# I have problems with hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I programmed a button in html to move when clicked and to get smaller when hovered.
However after I click the button it doesn't get smaller anymore.
Any idea why or how to fix it?

```js
$("#Hide").on("click",function()
  {
  if (hide==0)
    {
    hide = 1;
    $("#Hide").css( { "transform":" translate(-5px,-5px)" })
    }
  else if (hide==1)
    {
    hide=0;
    $("#Hide").css( { "transform":" translate(0px,0px)" })
    }
  });
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
.button:hover {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
#Hide {
  width: 54px;
  background: url(hide.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="Hide">X</button>
```

Comment: Would you please share a fiddle link of your issue?

Comment: from where come hide global ?

Comment: @SifatHaque There's no need for Fiddles or links. Executable code can be made right here in the question.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by the fact that you are using transform function twice in CSS and jQuery - and only one is used - style="" (added by jQuery is used).

You can move that button with `position: relative; top: -5px; left: -5px;` instead of `transform: translate(-5px,-5px)`.

You can also toggle class after click and define 4 transform properties:

```
button {
    transform: scale(1) transform(0,0)
}

button:hover {
    transform: scale(.75) transform(0,0)
}

button.clicked {
    transform: scale(1) transform(-5px,-5px)
}

button.clicked:hover {
    transform: scale(.75) transform(-5px,-5px)
}
```

And in JS:

```
$('#Hide').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change css class `.button` to `button`, because there is no such class in your document.

```js
$("#Hide").on("click",function()
  {
  if (hide==0)
    {
    hide = 1;
    $("#Hide").css( { "transform":" translate(-5px,-5px)" })
    }
  else if (hide==1)
    {
    hide=0;
    $("#Hide").css( { "transform":" translate(0px,0px)" })
    }
  });
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
button:hover {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
#Hide {
  width: 54px;
  background: url(hide.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="Hide">hide button</button>
```